# Can you use the academical Post-nominal letters without finishing the course?

Tags: professionalism

A student taken her Master's degree but eventually didn't complete her study. She only finished 36 units out of prescribed 42 units. Can she use her Post-nominal degree even she didn't complete her 42 units although she currently enrolled in the remaining 6 units?

Comment: The answer is no, as indicated by the existing answers, but I am curious where you're proposing to "use" the post nominal letters. On a resume? (but you didn't mention listing the degree on a resume, so perhaps not). In an email signature? Or where?

Answer (score 12):

She doesn't have a masters degree; she should not pretend that she has. So no - she cannot use her post-graduate degree as part of her title until she's completed the remaining six units.

If in doubt, she can check with her college.

Answer (score 8):

> Can you use the academical Post-nominal letters without finishing the
> course?

No.

Universities formally award degrees - usually upon completion of the required course of study. Until the degree is actually awarded, you should not use the degree indication (letters). Doing so would be the equivalent of lying.

Answer (score 0):

You get the right to use the post-nominal letters **when and only when the relevant degree is granted/conferred**, which will usually be either at some kind of graduation ceremony, or "in absentia" where you aren't physically present when it's granted, but there is still a formal process.

Occasionally in individual cases there can be a process where a degree is granted where the person had fulfilled all the requirements except the last, and then couldn't complete due to ill-health (in the UK I know this as [aegrotat](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/aegrotat) but there may be other names for it elsewhere). However it doesn't seem like that applies here since the person is currently enrolled in the final 6 units.

Using those letters is equivalent to saying "I have a Master's degree" (or whatever the letters relate to) and as such it follows the same rules, you wouldn't state that you have a Master's degree when you are actually just finishing up the last few requirements, so you wouldn't use those letters either.

To give you/her the benefit of the doubt about motivation for asking this: the letters don't indicate "currently on track to receive a Master's degree" but rather, "I have been granted the Master's degree already". So the short answer is no.